# Add Progressbar in each recycler view cell in android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, download, android-progressbar

I am new in android and i am making a ringing tune downloader app. In this app i have a recycler view with list of ringing tunes . When user clicks download button i want to show a progress bar in each cell. I know the RecyclerView recycles any old views and thus want a way around that atleast for the progressbars.

What would be the ideal way to implement this?

My adapter class

```
public class TrackListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    //to reference the Activity
    private final Activity context;
    private final RecyclerViewClicks recyclerViewClicks;
    private final ArrayList<Track> trackList;



    public TrackListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Track> trackList, RecyclerViewClicks recyclerViewClicks){

        this.context = context;
        this.recyclerViewClicks = recyclerViewClicks;
        this.trackList = trackList;


    }


    public ArrayList<Track> getData() {
        return this.trackList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tracklist_row,null);
        TrackListView rowView = new TrackListView(view);

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Track currentTrack = this.trackList.get(position);

        TrackListView trackListView = (TrackListView) holder;
        trackListView.title.setText(currentTrack.getName());
        trackListView.track.setText(currentTrack.getArtist());
        Picasso.get().load(currentTrack.getArtUrl())
                .resize(100,100)
                .into(trackListView.imageView);

//        if(currentTrack.isDownloaded())
//        {
//            trackListView.download.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//        }
//        else
//        {
//            trackListView.download.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//        }

    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return trackList.size();
    }

    class TrackListView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener
    {

        TextView title, track;
        ImageView imageView;
        Button download;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        TextView progressText;
      //  DownloadProgress downloadProgress;

        public ProgressBar getProgressBar() {
            return progressBar;
        }

        public TrackListView(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            track = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            download = itemView.findViewById(R.id.download);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgress);



            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    recyclerViewClicks.onButtonClicked(getAdapterPosition(),view,(Button) view);
                }
            });



        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            return false;
        }
    }



}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    ArrayList<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();
    RecyclerView trackListView;
    TrackListAdapter trackListAdapter;
    private File direct;
    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        AndroidNetworking.initialize(getApplicationContext());



         trackListAdapter = new TrackListAdapter(this, tracks, new RecyclerViewClicks() {
             @Override
             public void onItemSelected(int position, View v) {

             }

             @Override
             public void onButtonClicked(int position, View cell, Button button) {

                 Track selectedTrack = tracks.get(position);
                 downloadMusic(selectedTrack,cell);

             }

             @Override
             public void onLongClicked(int position) {

             }
         });
//
        trackListView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.trackListView);
        trackListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        trackListView.setAdapter(trackListAdapter);
......
......
```

I am using AndroidNetworking libs for downloading data from server.
Please Help

Comment: You could have a float field in the `Tracker` data, that will be saved whenever the progress of progress bar will change .

Comment: How i update each cell with download progress ?

Comment: Simply when progress bar updates, `tracker.setDownloadProgress(int progress);`

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I built for a RecyclerView which cells contain a content layout that when clicked on loads an audiocast mp3. **The first approach is optimal** as it stores the loading information temporarily in memory whereas the second approach is better suited for storing information that needs to be contained for a long period of time, not UI data.

## Loading State In Memory (*Best Solution*)

When content in the *RecyclerView* is selected the *ViewModel* stores either an Array or HashMap of the unique item id. When the *RecyclerView* cell's content has loaded it changes the view state of the content id in the Array or HashMap to loaded. The layout is bound to the *ViewModel* displaying the *ProgressBar* accordingly.

## Loading State On Disk

The *Content* model contains an attribute so that the loading state is updated in the Room SQLite database. The layout is already data bound to the *Content* model and will show the loading bar according to the model's attribute.